# Get project path commited from eclipse

Tags: java, bash, unix, svn, hook

I have created post-commit hook script for my svn repository. When I make commit from console I can get project (the checkout project) path - using 'pwd' order, because the hook is executed in this directory. But when I commit from Eclipse, I can't get path to project.

Is there any simple method to get that?

Of course I can get the commited project name using svn commands like svnlook changed and then find it on my disk, but this solution is unreliable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be helpful to to understand what it is you're trying to do with the hook... I'm a little confused as the post-commit hook is going to run on the server - not the client.

Comment: Oh, you are right. That changed my view.Thanks!